# Natlib on overleaf not working properly

Tags: overleaf

After hours of searching, I decide to ask for your help on the natlib of overleaf. First, my project is compiled successfully by TexStudio which display correctly the citations in my local computer. I had put all the .bib files in the same folder with my main tex file.

However, when I put it on the overleaf, it produces question marks on these citations. Oveleaf recognizes the bib files by autocompleting just fine and compiles the document successfully, but displays question marks for all `cite` or `citep` commands.

Here my sample of citation in the file Text.bib:

```
@article{leuz_economics_2016,
    title = {The {Economics} of {Disclosure} and {Financial} {Reporting} {Regulation}: {Evidence} and {Suggestions} for {Future} {Research}: {Disclosure} and {Financial} {Reporting} {Regulation}},
    volume = {54},
    issn = {00218456},
    shorttitle = {The {Economics} of {Disclosure} and {Financial} {Reporting} {Regulation}},
    url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1111/1475-679X.12115},
    doi = {10.1111/1475-679X.12115},
    language = {en},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2019-03-12},
    journal = {Journal of Accounting Research},
    author = {Leuz, Christian and Wysocki, Peter D.},
    month = may,
    year = {2016},
    pages = {525--622},
    file = {Leuz and Wysocki - 2016 - The Economics of Disclosure and Financial Reportin.pdf}
}
```

Overleaf autocomplete for cite command as `\cite{leuz_economics_2016}`

my bibliography style in the main tex file is as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{apa}

\bibliography{Text}
```

And the Overleaf system log is as follows:

> Package natbib Warning: Citation `leuz_economics_2016' on page 2
>   undefined on input line 96

EDIT: Thanks to the suggestion of @David Carlisle, it seems the Overleaf did not produce the .bbl file. I tried to upload the .bbl from my computer which run successfully, but the problem still persists on Overleaf.

Comment: that presumably means that bibtex did not run or it ran but there was an error and it did not generate a new bbl file, impossible to tell from the information you have posted so far.

Comment: I do not know exactly how overleaf compile the docs, but I think your point might correct, how can I check if new bbl files are generated?

Comment: I don't have an overleaf account, someone will answer I guess. but the latex log file will show if a bbl file is input or if the whole bbl is missing

Comment: I mange to download the compiled docs in zip using the guidance here: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_do_I_download_the_automatically_generated_files_(e.g._.bbl,_.aux,_.ind,_.gls)_for_my_project%3F_My_publisher_asked_me_to_include_them_in_my_submission). And I do not find the .bbl file. It seems BibTeX did not run in Overleaf

Comment: I'm on support staff at Overleaf - in general bibtex does run on the site and .bbl files are produced and cached. If you could email us with your project's URL (just copied from the browser address bar) at support@overleaf.com, we'll be happy to look into it.